# Create navigation menu to show all items when hovering with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to create a special navigation menu which looks similar to that of Harvard School Website.

I mean when hovering on an ul, all `li` of `ul` will be dropdown at the same time and highlight that category as well.

[image]

Moreover, I want to use `bootstrap` for this.

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: You can use `data-hover` property instead of `data-toggle` by adding this [**js**](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/2.0.2/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js). And use css property to highligh it on hover like `ul li a:hover`.

Comment: What about the my former expectation? I mean I want all `li` tags of al `ul` tags will be shown at the same time? It looks like that your example does not mention. @Unknown User

Comment: Can anyone give detail step, I'm new to jQuery?